# What are the numbers (calculated by the given expression) called?

Tags: education

The numbers calculated by the expression:

$$ T(n) = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} $$

are called [Triangular numbers](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Triangular_number).

What are the numbers (calculated by the expression below) called?

$$ T(n) = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2} $$

Do they have any name at all?

Comment: Those are exactly the same numbers, just shifted, so that would still be the triangular numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I was suspecting they may be called as "anti triangular numbers" or something like that. I thought they name may differ because those numbers describe the number of entries in the triangular matrix with and without the diagonal. EDIT: if I think about it, well there is no reason to call them differently even thou their connection to the matrices.

Comment: A bit late $$T(n+1) = \frac{(n+1)(n +1 - 1)}{2}=\frac{(n+1)(n)}{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're still triangular numbers. Shift by $1$ like so: $n\mapsto n-1$.